# Programmatically display Highstocks legend

Tags: charts, highcharts

Using Highstocks 1.2.4.

By configuration the overall legend is enabled while the showInLegend option for all series are enabled. So the legend is not display play default fine....how can I enable/display the legend by clicking on a button?

```
chart.options.legend.enabled = true
chart.redraw()
chart.legend.render()
```

has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I found:

$("#remove").click(function() {

```
item.options.showInLegend = false;
item.legendItem = null;
chart.legend.destroyItem(item);
chart.legend.render();
```

});

Read the complet example

http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/MtwGc/

Answer (score -1):

You can use this construction

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
            chart.options.legend.enabled = true;
            chart.options.legend = new Highcharts.Legend(chart);
            chart.redraw();
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grNfK/1/