# Programmatically change legends in highstock or highchart

Tags: highcharts

To set visibility of legends before a highstock chart is created, I can do:

```
new Highcharts.StockChart({
   legend: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'left'
   }
});
```

After the chart is created I want to allow users to hide or move legends to a different location. I need something similar to chart.setTitle but for legends.

Please note, I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621370/programmatically-display-highstocks-legend) but didn't quite understand the suggestions in it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Right now something like this is not part of Highcharts, but it is planned plugin for that, check this: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/912335-draggable-legend-box

Answer (score 0):

The post that you linked to is correct, but not as complete as you may like. There is no way to set an option to turn the legend on and off and have the chart adjust the margins to the presence of the legend. However, by removing all the data series in the manner shown in the example you linked to, the chart disappears. You can then manually adjust the margin if you  know ahead of time where the legend will be and how much margin it has been given.

For example, if "chart" is the name of your highcharts object :

```
for (var a=0; a<window[id].Chart_dataseries.length; a++)
{
    chart.series[a].options.showInLegend = false;
    chart.series[a].legendItem = null;
    chart.legend.destroyItem(chart.series[a]);
    chart.legend.render();
}
```

You can then make the chart "reappear" by re-rendering the items.

```
for (var a=0; a<window[id].Chart_dataseries.length; a++)
{
    chart.series[a].options.showInLegend = true;
    chart.series[a].legend.renderItem(chart.series[a]);
    chart.legend.render();
}
```

I make this happen by linking the actions to a checkbox and when it is checked, the chart "reappears" and when it is unselected, the chart "disappears." I tried doing this with the following additional commands :

```
chart.options.legend.enabled=false; (or true)
chart.render();
```

This did indeed adjust the chart to fill the space taken by the legend when the legend was removed. However, it also left the box around the legend. I also allow my users to manually adjust the margin, so for me a valid option was letting the user "turn off" the legend and then manually adjust the margin.